# When I upload image then it sent me error from views I don't know how to solve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I run this it is not call context class and not go to controller it gives me below given error I don't know how to remove it.

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

And also tell me about inner exceptions why they come and how we solve them.

```
 public class Employee
            {
                [Key]
                public int EmpID { get; set; }
                [Required]
                [Display(Name = "First Name")]
                public string First_Name { get; set; }
                [Required]
                [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
                public string Last_Name { get; set; }
                [Display(Name ="Image")]
                public byte[] Images { get; set; }
        }

        public class CareerContext:DbContext
            {

                public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
            }

         public ActionResult Registration(Employee Emp)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files["Image"];
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        if (image != null)
                        {
                            Emp.Images = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                            image.InputStream.Read(Emp.Images, 0, image.ContentLength);
                        }
                        db.Employees.Add(Emp);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Resume");
                    }
                    return View();
                }
```

Please tell me about this error and how I can solve it, and tell me what is inner exceptions and how to handle them and why and when they called.

Comment: your question is unclaer, plese post what exception is coming and where it is coming

Comment: friend tell me what is inner exceptions and how we handle them @Sujit.Warrier

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider show me your file upload in your cshtml file

Comment: <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Images, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>                                                                                                              Valkyriee

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider have you included `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in your form? where do you get the exception from exactly? could you copy/paste the except type and name?

Comment: yes enctype = "multipart/form-data" is given                                                  An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. this exception is return

Comment: Can i suggest an alternative approach? would why you want to save your image into your database? wouldn't it be easier to upload it within the root of your application and save its address within your database instead which makes your queries faster and more secure? if you want i can give you an example in answer. @ZeeshanHaider

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider Is `db.SaveChanges();` throwing `DbUpdateException`? Check and mention inner exception here to find out which error has been occurred. You can save file location path instead of saving entire file content inside DB to improve performance.

Comment: how i can save its path

Comment: yes give me an example @Valkyriee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Model change the `byte` with `string` for fileAddress and create Upload folder within your root of your application:

```
    public ActionResult Registration(Employee Emp)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files["Image"];
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"),
                                Path.GetFileName(image.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
                image.SaveAs(path);
                //now save your entity in database `path` is the address of your file
                //var empolyee = new  Employee { Images = path };
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: by using this code how we retrieve pic and file from database and show it on view. @Valkyriee

Comment: what is "N" @Valkyriee

Comment: now this execption is throw.  An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\MVC concepts and projects\CareersFYP\CareersFYP\Upload\webdevelopercover letter.docx69f9f3b3-1afa-4ef4-8219-cc3478adb5d9'.

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider For Retrieval you can easily reference the Address to a `<img src"@model.Address">` , and "N" is basically creates a Guid based on numbers, the exception you are getting because u haven't created upload folder

Comment: still it gives exception System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider could post what are u inserting for update to entity framework?

Comment: give me your fb id or name i send u complete project of mine @Valkyriee

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider sorry mate i dont have fb, but you can upload it on github or something and i can have a look :D

Comment: give me your gmail i send u in your mail account